# Poisson Process conditional probability

Tags: poisson-process

Let $N(t)$ be a Poisson Process with rate $\lambda$

Find $\displaystyle P(N(4) \le 2N(2) \mid N(2) = 1) = \frac{\sum_{i = 0 }^2P(N(4) = i, N(2) = 1)}{P(N(2) = 1)} = ?$

Can I split this up using the independent increments?

Comment: Presuming "$N(t)$" means the number of events in the interval $[0,t],$ the assumption of independent increments is essential for making any progress at all.  But why haven't you proceeded to evaluate the answer to see whether it makes sense?  There's less work involved than writing the question!

Comment: As I wasn't entirely sure in which way to split it up: Namely, $P(N(4) - N(2)  = i - N(2), N(2) = 1)$ which seems incorrect but so does $P(N(4) - N(2) = i - 1, N(2) = 1) $.

Comment: You might find it helpful and revealing to adopt a more precise notation: let $N(s,t)$ be the number of events in the interval $(s,t]$ and note that $N(4)=N(0,4)=N(0,2)+N(2,4)=N(2)+N(2,4).$

Comment: @whuber this leads me to $P(N(0,4) \le 2N(0,2) \mid N(0,2) = 1) = P(N(2,4) = 0 ) + P(N(2,4) = 1) + P(N(2,4) = 2)$ and $N(2,4) \sim$ Poisson$((4-2)\lambda)$. Is this the correct logic?

Comment: Good work: It looks like you're well on your way to a correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\mathbb P(N(4)\leqslant 2N(2)\mid N(2)=1) &= \frac{\mathbb P(N(4)\leqslant 2N(2), N(2)=1)}{\mathbb P(N(2) = 1}\\
&= \frac{\sum_{i=0}^2 \mathbb P(N(4)=i, N(2)=1)}{\mathbb P(N(2)=1)}\\
&= \frac{\sum_{i=0}^2 \mathbb P (N(4) - N(2) = i,N(2)=1)}{\mathbb P(N(2)=1)}\\
&=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^2 \mathbb P (N(4) - N(2) = i)\mathbb P(N(2)=1)}{\mathbb P(N(2)=1)}\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^2 \mathbb P(N(4) - N(2) = i)\\
&= e^{-2\lambda}(1 + 2\lambda +2\lambda^2).
\end{align}